# How do I store and load byte array (or image) to/from Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

Is there a way to store byte array in to cql database? I tried with blob but it didn't work. The table still have the blob column but I can't load nor store it. Here the code to create table

```
CREATE TABLE tb (id int PRIMARY KEY, data blob);
```

The loading code

```
        public Image convertImgFromByte()
        {
            string query = "SELECT data FROM tb where id = " +id + " ALLOW FILTERING;";
            var results = DataConnection.Ins.session.Execute(query).FirstOrDefault();
            byte[] arr = results.GetValue<byte[]>("picture");
    
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
            {
                Image img= Image.FromStream(ms);
                return img;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Can anyones give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> > There are two possibilities
>
> Can you directly access the SQL in CLI and ensure the image exists.
> or
> The tag you are referring "picture" could be different as in the byte array you can also lookup with index.

Comment: Well, it seems that cassandra I queried doesn't have the blob column, it possible the table was mis-create